Why is Spring not detecting my SQL Server database?
This is my application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP9SKTQTI;databaseName=JurasickPark;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=sY£1Q_PT=9i3
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

An this is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


4.0.0
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>BackendJurasicTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>12.9.0.jre11-preview</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

But when I run the application, it does not recognize the created database or the driver,

It connects to the database but does not recognize the created table, and tries to create it again,
What can i do to fix that?

That is info, ignore it. You are using an external datasource not one configured by hibernate so it doesn't know that info.

You should post the actual exception in text form as well as the code that tries to setup your table
